# How to extract ip address from subject_alt_name field from OpenSSL certificates using API(not openssl commands) in C

Tags: c++, string, openssl, subject-alternative-name

My requirement is to extract ip address from openSSL certificates using OpenSSL API functions(not openSSL primitive commands).
I can use ASN1_STRING_data() to extract san field details, but how do i print the ip address from it.What is the data type of the ip address field

I am fetching common name and san field from certificates following the below code flow.I am able to fetch the common name, but having troubles with the SAN field

Using openssl api for C , was able to fetch the common name field but not the SAN ip field

```
common_name(X509* server_cert) 
{


   X509_NAME *subject_name = X509_get_subject_name((X509 *)server_cert);

int common_name_loc = X509_NAME_get_index_by_NID(subject_name, NID_commonName, -1);

  X509_NAME_ENTRY *common_name_entry = 
X509_NAME_get_entry(X509_get_subject_name((X509 *) server_cert), common_name_loc);

ASN1_STRING *common_name_asn1 = X509_NAME_ENTRY_get_data(common_name_entry);        

char *common_name_str = (char *) ASN1_STRING_data(common_name_asn1);
}



san_field(X509 *cert)
{

    STACK_OF(GENERAL_NAME) *san_names = NULL;
    // Try to extract the names within the SAN extension from the certificate
san_names = static_cast<STACK_OF(GENERAL_NAME)*>(X509_get_ext_d2i((X509 *)cert, NID_subject_alt_name, NULL, NULL));

    san_names_nb = sk_GENERAL_NAME_num(san_names);
    // Check each name within the extension
    for (i=0; i<san_names_nb; i++) 
{
       const GENERAL_NAME *current_name = sk_GENERAL_NAME_value(san_names, i);
    if (current_name->type == GEN_IPADD)
    {
    const char* ip_addrezz = reinterpret_cast<char*> 
        (ASN1_STRING_data(current_name->d.iPAddress));

        print ---------->ip_addrezz //issue here

    }
}   
}

How to extract SAN ip field from certificate
How to print the ip address extracted from SAN field of certificate/what is the data type of the ip field
Am i going in correct direction
```

Comment: Why do you assume the certificate you're parsing even has an IP address for a Subject Alternative Name?  Most certificates won't have any IP address type SAN entries, only DNS entries.

Comment: Am writing for a specific application where we use ip based SAN fields, so i am sure that the certificate has a IP address type SAN entry

Comment: Have you taken the time to use the `openssl x509 -text` option on the certificate and verified that any IP address listed isn't entered as a **DNS** entry?  The DNS SAN entries are just strings, and are misused as IP addresses often enough that RFC 5280/RFC 1123 has to mention it.  See [**IP address in SubjectAltName**](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/160787/ip-address-in-subjectaltname).

Comment: Yes I have verified Andrew..and it specifically holds a ip address , not a dns entry.IP is enforced into the certificates SAN field

Comment: You didn't read the linked question and answer, did you?  A "DNS" entry is a free-form string **that can hold an IP address**.  Your code will not find such an entry.  You also have to check `GEN_DNS` entries to see if they hold an IP address string.  Or you can use `X509_get0_extensions()` and then pass the stack of extensions and a `BIO_new( BIO_s_mem() )` to `X509V3_extensions_print()` and then use `BIO_gets()` to get lines of text that contain **all** extensions of **all** types from the extension stack that you can parse.

Comment: @AndrewHenle  i verified if the type is GEN_DNS and since it was not i used GEN_IPADD which was true.So as you said maybe i should try the second part - use X509_get0_extensions().........or is there any other direct way as easy as fetching a DNS string

Comment: Beware of a potential null pointer dereference. `sk_GENERAL_NAME_value()` calls `sk_value` which can return `NULL`. However your pointer `current_name` is not checked for NULL before dereferencing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i recently also stumbled upon this and i would like to document the answer that suited best for me (i hope i got the point of this question right):
[RFC5280 - Subject Alternative Name](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.6) states, that iPAddress is

> stored in the octet string in "network byte order"

```
When the subjectAltName extension contains an iPAddress, the address
MUST be stored in the octet string in "network byte order", as
specified in [RFC791].  The least significant bit (LSB) of each octet
is the LSB of the corresponding byte in the network address.  For IP
version 4, as specified in [RFC791], the octet string MUST contain
exactly four octets.  For IP version 6, as specified in
[RFC2460], the octet string MUST contain exactly sixteen octets.
```

Which in turn means, for an IPv4 address, you might use something like

```
std::stringstream ip{};
ip << (int)ip_addrezz[0] << '.' << (int)ip_addrezz[1] << '.' << (int)ip_addrezz[2] << '.' << (int)ip_addrezz[3]
return ip.str();
```

to print it.

I also found this [post](http://www.zedwood.com/article/c-openssl-parse-x509-certificate-pem) really helpful (the code above is copied from there).